# How to segregate wallet from bitcoin core | Run multiple wallets in different servers on one centralized bitcoin node

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client, bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin-cli

I am running bitcoin full node in a centralized server. I have many web applications running in various places. I want to connect this web applications with centralized full bitcoin node. How to install wallet in these web application server which will be connected to one centralized bitcoin full node. I want to generate address, make transactions and sign transaction independently in these web application server using wallet and send it to the application server. Application server need to communicate with wallet using rest apis. Finally this singed transaction should send to centralized bitcoin full node. How to do this?